# Azure AD B2C Create User with the Graph API error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, nullreferenceexception

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga) in order to set up my azure application and [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-create-a-user) to create a user in my `B2C` users AD: I get a `System.NullReferenceException` on `.AddAsync(user)`.

```
// Create the user account in the directory
var u = graphClient.Users; 
var v = u.Request();
var w = await v.AddAsync(user); // --> NullReferenceException: v is not null
```

- [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations)
- [Git source code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management)

In also tested followings:

```
var user = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "Adele Vance",
    MailNickname = "AdeleV",
    UserPrincipalName = "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
    },
    
};

// Create the user account in the directory
var u = graphClient.Users;
var v = u.Request();
var w = await v.AddAsync(user); //--> same error
```

Comment: Can you share the completed code (including the how you define the `user` and how you generate the `graphClient`)?  And what if you use `await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the Microsoft documentations. I updated my question.

Comment: Do you have the all users data in a file?

Comment: Check if you are getting data into a variable `dataFilePath` by adding a breakpoint in Visual Studio. This is the line where you should look. `string dataFilePath = Path.Combine(appDirectoryPath, config.UsersFileName);`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem, since it throws the same error if I create a user (as last update of my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the beta Nuget package `Microsoft.Graph.Beta Version="0.12.0-preview"`. I switched to the new ones `Microsoft.Graph Version="3.27.0" and Microsoft.Graph.Core Version="1.24.0"` and updated all the others.

I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/pull/14/files)